# Can you identify this yellow LEGO vehicle?

Tags: set-identification

I bought my grandson a box of LEGO and this was in it. I have tried searching for 3 days with brick numbers to find the set but can’t get any joy. If anyone can point me in the right direction I would be extremely grateful.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 20):

The set name is [Cool Cruiser (5767)](https://brickset.com/sets/5767-1/Cool-Cruiser). This is a 3-in-1 Creator set with pictured model being one of these three:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why did they put the _boring_ model in the featured position on the box?  (Or is that just me ...) (Possible answer: instead of trying to appeal to the 8yr olds who'd _use_ the set they were appealing to their mommies who'd _buy_ the set ...)

Comment: @davidbak Boring?? One person's or kid's boring is another's exciting, I presume.

Comment: @alex could you show your process for working this kind of thing out?  You're obviously quite good at it.   Do you filter on Brickset for colour and obviously unusual parts, ie "mostly yellow, with 4 bigger than normal wheels" ?

Comment: @Criggie Depending on a case I use Bricklink, Rebrickable and Brickset. But mostly Bricklink due to best part catalog and good set inventories. Then the process is rather simple - identify the most unique element+color combination as a starting point. Depending on rarity it may direct you the set in question or narrow down the research. Then pick up second part (and maybe 3rd). Sometimes I pickup two parts and compare which sets they are part of. In this case [Technic, Gear Rack 1 x 8 with Holes](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=6630&colorID=11&in=A) was sufficient enough.